# Why does String passed by reference doesn't change its value?

Tags: java, object, reference, arguments

Why does the piece of code bellow modifies only value in array `t` and doesn't change value of the string `s` as well? I expected that String would also be changed because of its object properties.

```
class A {
    private int i = 0;
    private String s = "";
    private int[] t = new int[1];

    void m() {
        B.m(i, s, t);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "i=" + i + ", s=" + s + ", t[0]=" + t[0];
    }
}

class B{
   public static void m(int i, String s, int[] t){
      i += 1;
      s += "1";
      t[0] += 1;
   }  
}

public class Zad {

   public static void main( String [ ] args ){
      A a = new A() ;
      System.out.println(a);
      a.m();
      System.out.println(a);
   } 
}
```

Comment: The difference is between *assigning* vs. *mutating*.  Re-assigning a variable to a new value doesn't mutate whatever the previous value referenced.

Comment: In `b#m (int i,  String s, int [] t)`, `i`, `s`, and `t`, are names of *local* variables.  A `String` is immutable, so `s += "1";` creates a new String, changing the local `s` to refer to the result of the concatenation.  Because Java is pass by value, the argument in the caller is not changed. Check  page linked to in the "Closed question" box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what happening in your code: In Java, when you pass primitive types (like `int`) to a method, you pass the value itself. Any modification made to the parameter within the method do not affect the original value outside the method. This is known as "pass-by-value". This you may already know.

In definition of class `b`, `i`, `s`, and `t` are local variables within the method `m()`. It means, changes made to these variables do not affect the original values in the calling code.

When you call instance method `a.m();` in your main method:

```java
A a = new A();
System.out.println(a);  // Output: i=0, s=, t[0]=0
a.m();
System.out.println(a);  // Output: i=0, s=, t[0]=1
```

You'll see that the value of `t[0]` has changed because arrays in Java are objects, and modifications to their elements are reflected outside the method. However, the values of `i` and `s` remain unchanged because they are primitive types or immutable objects (like `String`), and any changes made to them within the method are local and don't affect the original values.